# The confusing part of a class object ' return self '

Tags: python-3.x

```
class mynumbers:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

This code has been written by someone else and i don't understand why they used return self can someone explain thise piece of confusing python code ?

1 - Why return self ?

2 - What is the logic behind this ?

3 - Which object is it gonna return ?

Comment: That is how you implement an iterator.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__iter__#iterator-types

Comment: but when you leave that ' return self ' what is it gonna actually return ?

Comment: I guess I should add that your class being returned as an iterator is essentially useless without a `__next__` method also, I am certain someone else can explain it better than I can which is why I am hesitant to actually post an answer

Comment: If you don't define `__iter__`, then objects of this class are not iterable.  It's a signal.  The `__iter__` method needs to return the iterator.  Sometimes, a class will hold a list, and you can return the list here.  But often, the objects are themselves iterable, so we return `self`.

Comment: but i don't understand ' return self ' it is confusing a little bit the function is empty do you mean it is gonna return the class instance object ?????

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your questions as best as I can and create a few examples.

For your first question, that is simply how implementing iterable support works in python.

For your second question it facilitates the looping mechanism by automatically calling the **next** method and returning the resulting value.

For your third question if you literally call object.**iter**() on a non container-like object then it will literally just returns `self` the class instance object.

As it stands your example method is kind of useless. In order to meet the requirements of the iterator implementation no container types need to implement an `__iter__` and a `__next__` method.

For example:

```
class MyNumbers:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.start < self.end:
            self.start += 1
            return self.start
        raise StopIteration
```

Because we added the next method it now works as an iterator so we
Can do things like for loops and list comprehension

```
numbers = MyNumbers(10, 20)
total = 0
for i in numbers:
    total += i
    print(i, total)
```

Output:

```
11 11
12 23
13 36
14 50
15 65
16 81
17 98
18 116
19 135
20 155
```

You can also use the `iter` and `next` built in functions.

```
numbers = MyNumbers(300, 307)
print(next(numbers))  # output 301
print(next(numbers))  # output 302
print(next(numbers))  # output 303
```

You can find out more details in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__iter__#iterator-types).

Comment: so from what i understand 'return self' is going to return the instance object am i right ?

Comment: yes yoou are correct

Comment: i wanna understand one more thing

Comment: when i call __iter__ of course it is gonna return me an object from the class instance but which object ? are they the arguments of the instance or the whole instance with its name too ???

Comment: It depends on the class.  It will either return a the regular class instance or it will return a generator. @Tarek  In this example it would return a regular class instance